# Performance vs memory Lists

Tags: java, performance, list, memory

What would be better ?

Say we would have a certain class `mainClass` which has a `List<BigClass>` with `List<Foo>foos`....

`Foo` itself has a `List<Boo>`

If the goal was to be able to get all the `Boo`'s for all the elements of `foos`.
Would it then be better to keep another `List<Boo>` within the `BigClass`and insert the corresponding `Boo` elements if a user was to insert a new `Foo` into  `foos`?

or would it be better to generate this total  `Boo` list from within 'BigClass` each time the users asks for this list ?

main question here is, would you have to chose performance vs memory here ?

PS.
sorry for the broad title, didn't quite know how to name this question :/

Comment: Use the method that is most easy to understand. That is the primary concern. Never worry about performance or memory until it is a problem, because it probably won't be.

Comment: *would you have to chose performance vs memory here*: yes, obviously. You would also have to consider correctness, maintainability, robustness and readability. The second solution is much simpler to get right than the first one.

Comment: @JBNizet , yes, but if done right. Would the first option be prefered ?

Comment: @MikeDunlavey , wouldn't this approach be very "slow working", "redundant working"? if you had to search for those functions where you could free some more memory or performance ea time you hit a wall ?

Comment: What Mike Dunlavey said was correct. Because nowadays memory is not an issue. Only if you are passing it as web parameter or working in mobile device where memory is limited, then yes you should worried.

Comment: @Koen: I've been programming over half a century - so what do I know? First make it right. Then, if there's a problem, fix the problem. If you want to know how I find performance problems, there's a video [*here*](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCGwyNGICQ4RHmcYcQIG9gxw), and numerous discussions online.

Comment: @KoenDemonie even if done right, it's still much harder to maintain. Code evolves constantly. Implementing a complex solution to gain a few milliseconds when the simple solution is fast enough is not a good idea.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey , thank you for the video link.

Comment: @JBNizet , I am still pretty new to the whole memory usage/performance system, but i could image if a `Foo` object would exist out of couple thousand `Boo` objects and a `manclass` out of of couple thousand  `BigClass` objects that these milisecconds could be translated into seconds,minutes ?  please correct me if i'm wrong...

Comment: @Koen: You're welcome. I had your concerns once too, when machine were *way* slower and smaller. But you are thinking about speed and memory issues *before* writing the program. That's the wrong time to think about them. Think about them *after*, so you're dealing in brass tacks, not in hypotheticals. You can always fix the program after you write it. You can't really fix it before you write it. (You know the way authors work when faced with a blank page - write something, anything, even if it's awful. Then go back and revise it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to both get all the `Boo`s and also keep `Boo`s grouped (i.e. `Boo`s that belong to some `Foo`), then I'd say the best would be to return a *view* of all the `Boo`s contained in `BigClass`, no matter which `Foo` they belong to.

To accomplish this, you could use [Google Guava `Iterables`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#Iterables) or [Java 8 `Stream.flatMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-), depending on your Java version.

With Google Guava:

```
class BigClass {

    List<Foo> foos = new LinkedList<Foo>();

    public Iterable<Boo> allBoos() {
        return Iterables.concat(this.foos);
    }
}

class Boo {
    final int a;

    Boo(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(this.a);
    }
}

class Foo
    implements Iterable<Boo> {

    List<Boo> boos = new LinkedList<Boo>();

    @Override
    public Iterator<Boo> iterator() {
        return this.boos.iterator();
    }
}

public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Boo b1 = new Boo(1);
        Boo b3 = new Boo(3);
        Boo b5 = new Boo(5);

        Boo b2 = new Boo(2);
        Boo b4 = new Boo(4);
        Boo b6 = new Boo(6);

        Foo odd = new Foo();
        odd.boos.addAll(Arrays.asList(b1, b3, b5));

        Foo even = new Foo();
        even.boos.addAll(Arrays.asList(b2, b4, b6));

        BigClass b = new BigClass();
        b.foos.add(odd);
        b.foos.add(even);

        System.out.println(b.allBoos()); // [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6]
    }
}
```

The best of this approach is that the `Iterable` that Guava returns is *lazy*, meaning that no new collection or list is created and filled with any element. Instead, the returned `Iterable` is a view whose `Iterator` consumes elements from the first `Iterable` and, when exhausted, "jumps" to the next `Iterable` and consumes its elements, and "jumps" to the next one, and so on, until the last element of the last `Iterable` is consumed.

With Java 8:

```
class BigClass {

    List<Foo> foos = new LinkedList<Foo>();

    public Iterable<Boo> allBoos() {
        Stream<Boo> s = this.foos.stream().flatMap(
            f -> f.getBoos().stream());
        return s::iterator;
    }
}

class Boo {
    final int a;

    Boo(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(this.a);
    }
}

class Foo {

    List<Boo> boos = new LinkedList<Boo>();

    public List<Boo> getBoos() {
        return this.boos;
    }
}

public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Boo b1 = new Boo(1);
        Boo b3 = new Boo(3);
        Boo b5 = new Boo(5);

        Boo b2 = new Boo(2);
        Boo b4 = new Boo(4);
        Boo b6 = new Boo(6);

        Foo odd = new Foo();
        odd.boos.addAll(Arrays.asList(b1, b3, b5));

        Foo even = new Foo();
        even.boos.addAll(Arrays.asList(b2, b4, b6));

        BigClass b = new BigClass();
        b.foos.add(odd);
        b.foos.add(even);

        List<Boo> list = new ArrayList<>();
        b.allBoos().forEach(boo -> list.add(boo));

        System.out.println(list); // [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6]
    }
}
```

The same considerations regarding *laziness* apply here.

Comment: This seems very nice, Since (as i understand) it does not consume any extra memory. But it will however have to iterate every single time over and over again when a call to get all the `boo`S is made right ?

Comment: @Koen No, it's a view. In other words, a wrapper around all lists of `Boo` within every `Foo`. It's an `O(1)` operation.

Comment: @Koen To be crystal-clear: elements are finally traversed when the returned `List` is iterated.

Comment: So basicly you could see it as if all `Boo` lists within `Foo` were to be attached to eachother ? This would be created each time (again and again) whenever we call the method `getBoos()` ?

Comment: @Koen Yes, you could see it that way, however nothing that depends on the number of `Boo`s or on the number of `Foo`s will be created when you call either `allBoos()` or `getBoos()`. In my example, if I had created 10,000 `Foo`s, each one with 10,000 `Boo`s, calling `allBoos()` would have taken exactly the same time as the 2 `Foo`s with 3 `Boo`s from the code above.

Comment: So basicly it doesn't consume extra memory nor does it drastically speed down the performance?

Comment: @Koen Exactly! You could see it as if elements were fetched when the `List` is iterated. In my example, this happens in the last line: `System.out.println(b.allBoos())`, in the `toString()` method of the returned `List`.

Comment: Very nice. Just weird I have never heard of this then... Thank you

Comment: @KoenDemonie I've introduced a fix in java8's example, so that getting the `Iterable<Boo>` is now completely lazy (it was fetching the entire collection before the fix).

Answer (score 2):

You can have both behaviors with a single implementation. Just create your own implementation of List in mainClass (probably an inner class named FooList, or maybe even an anonymous inner class). Make FooList's methods transparently present all the individual Foo lists as a single list. For example, the implementation of FooList.iterator() will transparently instantiate an iterator on each individual Foo list in turn, so that it will appear to be iterating through a single large list.